# Operators from $\ell_p$ to $\ell_q$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Let $1\leqslant p<q<\infty$. Denote $L(\ell_p)$ the space of bounded operators on $\ell_p$. Let $B_{L(\ell_q)}$ [was $B_{L(\ell_p)}$ ] be the closed unit ball of $L(\ell_q)$ [was $L(\ell_p)$] considered as a subset of $L(\ell_p)$ [was $L(\ell_p)$]. Is it closed in $L(\ell_p)$ [was $L(\ell_p)$]?

EDIT: I made a correction.

EDIT 2: You are right. Please delete my question.

Comment: I don't understand how your inclusions are supposed to work, maybe you want to expand on that? We have $\ell^p \subset \ell^q$. Now take $x \in \ell^{q} \smallsetminus \ell^p$ and take a rank one operator on $\ell^q$ of norm one projecting on the span of $x$. How does that give an operator on $\ell^p$ with values in $\ell^p$?

Answer (score 2):

$B_{L(\ell^p)}$ is not even contained in $L(\ell^q)$.

Take $p=1$, $q=2$, and define $T : \ell^1 \to \ell^1$ by 
$$Tx = \left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty x(i), 0, 0, \dots\right).$$
$T$ is certainly a bounded operator on $\ell^1$, with operator norm 1, but it does not have a continuous extension to $\ell^2$.  Let $x_n = (1, \frac{1}{2}, \dots, \frac{1}{n}, 0, 0, \dots)$.  Then $x_n$ converges in $\ell^2$, but $\|T x_n\|_{\ell^2} \to \infty$.

**Edit**: The question was edited to reverse the desired inclusion, but this  doesn't hold either, for even more trivial reasons.  A bounded operator on $\ell^q$ may map some elements of $\ell^p$ to elements of $\ell^q \setminus \ell^p$.

Comment: Apologies, I meant the opposite inequality.

Comment: @MarkNeuer: I think that makes it worse.  See my edit.

Comment: Ah, we're in agreement here :)

Comment: Sure, can you please delete it? :)

Comment: @MarkNeuer Why are you so keen on deleting your question? Others might benefit from it if it stays.